# Putting n balls into boxes to approximate global distribution

Tags: mathematical-optimization, counting

Suppose we have number **n** of balls. A ball i has a **color c<sub>i</sub>** from the set of colors C. The goal is put the balls into boxes of **the same size K**, and we want the distribution of colors inside the box is the same as the global distribution (i.e before partitioning). Could we formalize the size of boxes i.e K, needed to achieve the optimal partitioning?

Thanks,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming

Comment: How many boxes are present?